# Convert SQL query with INNER JOINs, GROUP BY, ORDER BY, and MAX() to LINQ

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I am currently trying to convert the following SQL query:

```sql
SELECT ref.pa_nbr, MAX(ins.ins_id)
FROM referral ref
INNER JOIN ins i ON ref.referral_nbr = i.referral_nbr
INNER JOIN pm p ON i.pm_nbr = p.pm_nbr AND p.pm_group = 2
WHERE ref.pat_nbr = @pat_nbr
GROUP BY ref.pat_nbr
ORDER BY ref.pat_nbr
```

into a LINQ expression. I have tried several times but have not received the correct results. The latest attempt can be seen in the following:

```
var medicaidNumber = 
    (from referral in context.REFERRALs
     join ins in context.INSs on referral.REFERRAL_NBR equals ins.REFERRAL_NBR
     join pm in context.PMs on ins.PM_NBR equals pm.PM_NBR
     where referral.P_NBR == patid && pm.PM_GROUP == 2
     orderby referral.PAT_NBR
     group referral by referral.PAT_NBR).FirstOrDefault();
```

Could someone take a look at what I am doing and see if there's another way to go about this? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Where does `ind` come from in your sql?  Or is that a typo for `ins`?

Comment: where is the medicaidNumber coming from? You have to select that at the end of your linq query before you call FirstOrDefault

Comment: That should be ins, it was a typo

Comment: there is a difference SQL query has pm_group = 2 in the join where as LINQ query has it in the where clause . it should work. i had this issue once before with the inner join where i have used where clause condition in the join .

Answer (score 0):

You have to group into a variable that you can then do the max aggregation on.

```
from referral in context.REFERRALs
join ins in context.INSs on referral.REFERRAL_NBR equals ins.REFERRAL_NBR
join pm in context.PMs on ins.PM_NBR equals pm.PM_NBR
where referral.P_NBR == patid && pm.PM_GROUP == 2
orderby referral.PAT_NBR
group ins.INS_Id by referral.PAT_NBR into grp
select new { PAT_NBR = grp.Key, MaxINSId = grp.Max() };
```